# How to test function returning next method with Hippie?

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I've got a function which returns next(); as a function to allow next route to be called and it's used for checking the token as an interceptor and allows function to go through.

The problem I have now is that I want to test this particular function and I don't have next route it's just that one so when I use some API testing tool like Hippie and make a request it hangs and does nothing until timed out.

So the test call I have is like below with [Hippie](https://github.com/vesln/hippie):

```
    hippie(server)
        .header('token', token)
        .json()
        .put('/token')
        .send(tokenRequest)
        .end(function(err, res, body) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            done();
        });
```

Basically token endpoint is linking to token interceptor and that returns next();

How do I make this into testable state?

Answer (score 0):

the function shouldn't be returning next(), it should call next after it's completed its operation. E.G.:

```
    module.router.post('/*', function(req,res,next){
       middleware.doSomething()
       .then(function(){
          next();
       });
    });

    module.router.post('/user', function(req,res,next){
       //comes here from the next() above
       res.status(501).send("unimplemented");
    });
```